# how am I able to write different languages in one latex file?

Tags: babel, languages

I'm on a Mac and I'm using the standard package that is available for Mac. I've tried to include `babel` and it doesn't work this way. what is the standard way of enabling a different language in LaTeX? If it is `babel` should I install something separate to get it to work?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

this is english and  español

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `Did not work` is no very well-defined description. Did you use something like `\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}`, for example? Basically you can write in any language in LaTeX (given the right input encoding is given, the advantage of `babel` or `polyglossia` is that those packages take care of the typographical pecularities of the relevant languages/cultures

Comment: @ChristianHupfer didn't work in a sense that  when I run it, English is shown perfectly but the other language that I define will be in question marks. for instance if I write this is Español I will get this is ???????

Comment: Please provide your document that you have tried to run (and failed apparently) in your post above.

Comment: probably you are missing `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` but really you have given no indication of your input nor of any error messages you got. which makes it impossible to help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you're right. I just wrote this for instance to keep it simple: \documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

this is english and  español

\end{document} if I remove the word español it will run if not it will not even run in this example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I did, thank you for taking the time to help

Comment: @DannyNelson: For typing `español` you don't need `babel` at all, `inputenc` is sufficient. I've run your example on TL 2016 (Linux) and got the expected result. If you don't need language - dependent spacing etc. rules or translations of `\chaptername` etc. you can omit `babel`, most likely.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer and hyphenation, too. The correct way is `this is English {\selectlanguage{spanish} y esto es español}.` Although really hyphenation in mixed language documents is not so well defined, methinks...  By the way, the default (main) language is the last one in the list of the `babel` optional argument, so OP should have them reversed.

Comment: @Rmano: Sure, but apparently not even the simple way (i.e. without `\selectlanguage`) seems to work right now for the O.P.

Comment: You shouldn't get all question marks. With that input, I'd expect perhaps one question mark at most. LaTeX doesn't know the `E` is Spanish and not English anyway - it is just an `E`. That said, you should also add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but I don't think this will solve the problem described which doesn't even make sense to me right now.

Comment: Saying that you use "the standard package that is available for Mac" is very uninformative. Did you mean to state that you use MacTeX? If so, do you have MacTeX2016 installed? Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are very few clues in the question but if

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

this is english and  español

\end{document}
```

is saved in UTF-8 and processed with pdflatex you get

[image]

If the same text is saved as latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) then you get a latex error due to the utf8 declaration so the terminal message is:

```
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \UTFviii@four@octets was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.8
```

If you scroll past this error you get

[image]

so missing text but no question marks.

If you add `\listfiles` and save the file back in UTF-8 then latex will output a list of file versions to the terminal and log.

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 english.ldf    2017/01/24 v3.3q English support from the babel system
 spanish.ldf
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
 ***********
```

Comment: you didn't mention that main language should be last for `babel`.

Comment: @DannyNelson use your editor to save your file in UTF-8

Comment: @David Carlisle and how is that done?) I should add a line somewhere?

Comment: @David Carlisle , ok I got it , all I had to do was to make a new file and then select it from the drop down when latex creates the files for the first time. I can't thank you enough for the help!

Comment: @DannyNelson yes possibly. Saving files is a feature of whatever editor you use so not directly latex related. But glad to see you sorted out a method.